# Alternatives to sink()

Tags: r

I'd like to write the output and messages to a file. I have this function-

```
  conn <- file("file")
  
  sink(conn, append=TRUE)
  sink(conn, append=TRUE, type="message")
```

And then to get rid of the sink I have

```
sink()
```

And it crashes nearly every time. I get an unexpected error after running `sink()`

What alternative functions will let me write output to a file?

Comment: `cat()` can also be used to write to files and `capture.output()` to capture output in the same way of `sink()`. However, getting unexpected errors after `sink()` is (somewhat) surprising to me. Why not post a full [mcve] to figure out the actual source of your error?